# Is this enum of two different types?

Tags: swift, types, enums

I'm following a tutorial and I noticed the author(s) declared this enum with what looks like to be multiple types.  Based on what I've read online from the Swift Standard Library, I understand enums can be of a certain type and enums do not support inheritance.  Is this enum of both String and CodingKey type?  Or is the name case a String type and the items case a CodingKey type?

```
private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case items
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html: *"Custom types state that they **adopt a particular protocol** by placing the protocol’s name after the type’s name, separated by a colon, as part of their definition."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't inheritance, it's two things:

1. A [raw value clause](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID149). This is a special form that speficies the "backing value" used to represent the `enum`'s cases. In this case, it's `String`. When an enum has chosen to have a String raw value, but the case doesn't specify a raw value, the name of the case is implicitly assumed to be the raw value of the case.
2. A protocol conformance clause, which declares that this enum conforms to `CodingKey`.